# Search half title using pgsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I'm using `pgsearch` for search functionality.
I have written below code in my model.

Movies.rb

```
pg_search_scope :search_it, :against => Movies.attribute_names,
:associated_against => {
:tags => [:name]
}
```

And im using it in controller like this:

```
if (params[:search].blank?)
@movies_filter = Movies.all
else
movies_filter = Movies.order(:name).search_it(params[:search])
end
```

Now the problem is that I only want to show avengers in result if `av,gers,ven` is searched.I'm getting result if I search by avengers(full word).

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following

```
include PgSearch

pg_search_scope :search_it, against: [:attribute_names],
  associated_against: {tags: :name}
```

**Texticle and PgSearch**

The `text_search` method is starting to get a little messy and it will only get worse if we search against more columns. Fortunately, there's a gem that can help up here. Texticle makes it easier to do full-text searching in Postgres. To use it we just need to add it to the application’s gemfile and then run `bundle` to install it.

```
gem 'texticle', require: 'texticle/rails'
```

Here is the full [episode of Rails pg_search](http://Full-Text%20Search%20in%20PostgreSQL) you can see this.

Hope it will help.